# How to start an Activity from a class extending BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, baseadapter

I am using the following code to generate a custom ListView. Everything is working fine, but when user clicks on the listview, i cannot make it to go to another class as Intents cannot be used in non Activity class.
Is there a way to start an activity for the below code???

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
String[] result;
Context context;
int[] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CustomAdapter(MainActivityList mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList,
        int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result = prgmNameList;
    context = mainActivity;
    imageId = prgmImages;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
    holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlist);
    holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewlist);
    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
            {
                //Intent is not working here
                                    //Here i need some help 
            }
            }
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}

}
```

I am stuck in this part of the project, please do help me..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Activity context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Intent cannot be used as i cannot extend Activity

Comment: @DarshanGowda you only need context. no need to extend Activity.

Comment: @DarshanGowda Intent has nothing to do with Activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html. You only need context which is already initialized in the constructor of adapter. `startActivity` is a method of activity. hence you need context to startactivity

Comment: yeah, my bad, thanks, it is working now. I was using 
    Intent intent= new Intent(currentClass.this,secondActivity.class);
        currentClass.this.startActivity(intent);


your answer fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to not overwork the `Adapter`, I'd register each row for a context menu using `registerForContextMenu(convertView)`. This way, you'll have to implement the `onCreateContextMenu()` and `onContextItemSelected()` outside the `Adapter`, probably within the `Activity` you're populating your `ListView`, and define the `startActivity()` inside that `Activity`, where it will work just fine.

An example follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  menu.setHeaderTitle("Context menu");
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Start the new Activity");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  final int mId = item.getItemId();

  switch (mId) {
    case 0:         // Entrar a un canal
      final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MySecondActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);

      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I didn't meant you have to extend your `Activity`. What I'm saying is that there's a point where you initialize your `ListView`, right? In that same file is where you would need to implement that two methods I added to my answer, and there you can get the `Context` as you will be executing this within some `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Comment: This also works but the answer i have accepted is much more simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this ..

```
public void onClick(View v){
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
yourIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
v.getContext().startActivity(yourIntent);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
   TextView mealName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealNameDietTXT);
    mealName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            SessionClass.subMealID=mealsArray.get(position).getMealComponentId();
            Intent i = new Intent(dietRadioAdapter.this.context, dietDetails.class);
           dietRadioAdapter.this.context.startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(currentClass.this,secondActivity.class);
        currentClass.this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();                       
    }
});
```